# Converting iQueryable to IEnumerable

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

What is the problem with my code below? It's not returning any items even when matching records are present in the database. If it's wrong, how can I convert my `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`?

```
public IEnumerable<TimelineItem> TimeLineItems { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<TimelineItem> GetTimeLineItems(int SelectedPID)
{
    TimeLineItems = (from t in db.TimelineItems
                     where t.ProductID == SelectedPID
                     select new { t.Description, t.Title }) as IEnumerable<TimelineItem>;
    return TimeLineItems;
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my opinion, if you are going to use linq then embrace it, get rid of that esoteric notation :)

```
   public IEnumerable<TimelineItem> GetTimeLineItems(int SelectedPID)
   {
      return db.TimelineItems.Where(tl => tl.ProductID == SelectedPID)
        .Select( tl => new TimelineItem {
            Description = tl.Description,
            Title = tl.Title })
        .AsEnumerable<TimelineItem>();
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

The reason you are getting `null` is because you are trying to convert an `IQueryable` based on an an *anonymous type* to `IEnumerable<TimelineItem>` (`new { t.Description, t.Title }` creates an instance of an anonymous type with two fields - `Description` and `Title`) You should remove the `Select` part to make it work.

If you would like to select only `Description` and `Title`, create a *named* type with these two fields, and return an `IEnumerable` of that type:

```
public class TitleDescr {
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}

public IEnumerable<TitleDescr> GetTimeLineItems(int SelectedPID)
{
    return from t in db.TimelineItems
                     where t.ProductID == SelectedPID
                     select new TitleDescr { t.Description, t.Title };
}
```

Comment: I don't want to select all items.I want to select only description and title ,that's why I am using Select

Comment: @sureshcd10cvvc Please see my edit for an explanation of what to do if you need a projection of your result.

Answer (score -1):

Use auto mapper to convert `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`

```
 StudentsModel IEmodel = new StudentsModel();//IEnumerable 
            try {
                var Queryablemodel = _tblStudents.GetQueryable().FirstOrDefault(x => x.CNIC == strCNIC && x.LoginPassword == strPassword);//IQueryable
               //conversion with Auto Mapper
                IEmodel = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Queryablemodel , IEmodel ); 
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                throw ex;
            }
```