# IQueryable to IEnumerable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public IEnumerable<Temp_Order> Get_Temp(string id)
{
    //List<Temp_Order> data = new List<Temp_Order>();
    IEnumerable<Temp_Order> data = db.Temp_Order
                                      .Join(db.Items, 
                                            t_id => t_id.ItemId, 
                                            I_id => I_id.ItemId,
                                            (t_id, I_id) => new  { t_id.Quantity, I_id.ItemName })
                                      .Where(x => x.ItemName == id);

    return data;
}
```

In this method I want `IEnumerable<Temp_Order>`. So I will use this in controller and return to the view.

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) E:\WORK\Projects\RMS_Live\RMS_Live\Models\Order.cs

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting iqueryable to IEnumerable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10098568/converting-iqueryable-to-ienumerable)

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis i think my error is due to Join in query. Link which you provided, in that link there no JOIN in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.90).aspx) is converting your query to an IEnumerable of an anonymous type. Add a [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=VS.100).aspx) on the end to cast is back to `Temp_Order`:

```
public IEnumerable<Temp_Order> Get_Temp(string id)
{
    //List<Temp_Order> data = new List<Temp_Order>();
    IEnumerable<Temp_Order> data = db.Temp_Order
                    .Join(db.Items, t_id => t_id.ItemId, I_id => I_id.ItemId, (t_id, I_id) => new  { t_id.Quantity, I_id.ItemName })
                    .Where(x => x.ItemName == id)
                    .Select(a => new Temp_Order
                        {
                            ItemName = a.ItemName,
                            Property2 = a.Property2,
                            //snip
                        });

    return data;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You indicate in the comments that you want all properties from both `Temp_Order` and `Item` which means you need another class. You can get away without creating another class, but it's much simpler in the long run. So first make your class, 2 ways spring to mind, you either replicate all the properties you need or just return the 2 objects, I'll use the latter:

```
public class OrderItem
{
    public Temp_Order Temp_Order { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

Now your function becomes this:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderItem> Get_Temp(string id)
{
    IEnumerable<OrderItem> data = db.Temp_Order
                    .Join(db.Items, 
                          t_id => t_id.ItemId, 
                          I_id => I_id.ItemId,
                          (t_id, I_id) => new OrderItem
                              {
                                  Temp_Order = t_id,
                                  Item = I_id
                              })
                    .Where(x => x.ItemName == id);

    return data;
}
```

And in your view, make sure you set the model type to `IEnumerable<OrderItem>` and you can access all the properties like this:

```
@Model.Temp_Order.ItemName
```

Comment: Thnx :D ... but how would i access Item table fields in Select?

Comment: `a` contains the fields of everything you select in the Join clause, so you only have `Quantity` and `ItemName` available.

Comment: .Select(a => new Temp_Order { Quantity = a.Temp_Order.Quantity, ItemName=a.Item.ItemName} ... it is giving error.... only Temp_Order fields can be accessed in this SELECT :(

Comment: Remember you are storing all this data inside `Temp_Order` objects, you cannot add your own properties to it.

Comment: So what should my return type be instead of Ienumerable<Temp_order>?   I want all fields of Temp_order and Item Table and display them in view.... plz help me